# How can I make accesible some operations of a Python application over the network?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a Python application that is executed to continually monitor the system to search anomalies. This project has connections to database to store information and a set of componentes that are in charge of different monitor tasks. Each component can be paused and resumed, and an in memory state (status, uptime, last anomaly detected, detection parameters...)

The question is: how can I expose the operations to pause and resumen (or even change the detection parameters) a component to a web client (for example a React webapp)?. All the options that I can think has problems:

- Integrate a Flask API: the fundamentals of a REST API is that they should be stateless, but my backend has state (components and their status).
- Separate Flask API. Here my problem is how communicate the Flask API with the backend. I have though in a message queue: the client send a request to the API, the API creates an event "start component 2", add it to the queue and the backend receives the event. But with this approach, the web client can not receive confirmation unless the request wait for another event from the backend with the result of the operation, which make the communication syncronous.

Maybe there is something that I'm missing and the solution is easier than all of this.

Comment: Common way is to make separate API methods: first will create some task and second will retrieve result once it will be ready. In that way you make request to `/create` and after that you starting to make requests to `/check` until result wiil be finally retrieved.

Comment: Thank you, Olvin. I've read something about this approach and it seems good. But should I make this /create and /check methods in a sepparate Flask API and the communicate it with the backend end, or it's okay to "integrate" those methods in an API inside the backend itself?

Comment: Both variants possible. Separate API which communicates with main server usually is more secure but it could be more complicated to maintain. If you want to integrate those methods in current backend, which is also absolutely ok, just make sure that all methods you don't want to be public are protected. There're plenty of guides where all steps of basic web app security listed, so I see no sense to explain it additionally. Choose method which fits your requirements better and proceed.

Comment: Okey, one last question: Let's assume that I integrate a Flask API inside the current backend. The start up method then has to do 2 things: init the flask app object (registering the views, etc) and init the backend status (creating the basic components and start the system monitoring). To to not use the flask development server, I should use a WSGI server like Guinicorn, but I only can use one worker because if I set 2 o more, then the init process of the backend will be executed several times, which is wrong.*I continue in the next comment*

Comment: From a performance point of view, this is ok because just one a thread is enough (only a few users will use the app at the same time, and the will not do a lot of queries. But I don't know if this is correct from a design/architecture point of view.

Comment: I have no idea how *(and why)* you want to init server using API method which have to be served ..... using server you want to init.

Comment: No, I haven't explained myself correctly. When I say "init the backend status", I mean execute the code that do de start up (create basic components and start them). And this code (I think) has to be in main.py file, where also is started the flask app object

Comment: All setup which have to be initialized for server functioning normally should be initialized on server start before any API call happens.